# Consulta C# separar jubilados y no jubilados

Tags: c#

He intentado solucionar este problema. Necesito que me separe jubilados de no jubilados. Estoy utilizando métodos get y set como encapsulamiento, además creé tres ciclos for, uno para realizar el ciclo de solicitarle al usuario el ingreso de nombres y edad a registrar. Y los otros dos for para mostrar datos guardados en los arreglos. Quedo agradecido, estoy iniciando en la programación y sería de mucha ayuda sus comentarios.

En la salida sale esto: la mujeres se pensionan con 57 años, hombres con 62 años. Agradezco sus ayudas.

**Las personas que pueden jubilarse son:**

Ana  con  59  años

**Las personas que NO pueden jubilarse son:**

juan  con  56  años

Ana  con  59  años

```
namespace Colpensiones. 
{
   internal class Validaciones
   {
      /* Creación de variables. */
      private int usuarios = 0;
      private int hombre = 62;
      private int mujer = 57;
           
      /* Creación de los métodos get y set para encapsular variable usuario. */
      public int getUsuarios()
      {
         return usuarios;
      }

      public void setUsuarios(int u)
      {
         usuarios = u;
      }

      /* Creación del metodo Metodo(), para realizar las operaciones que arrojen los resultados requeridos. */
      public int Metodo()
      {            
         /* Creación de arreglos para almacenar los valores ingresados por el usuario. */
         string[] nombres = new string[usuarios];
         byte[] edad = new byte[usuarios];
         byte[] sexo = new byte[usuarios];
        
         /* Creación de ciclo para repetir la operación de ingreso de datos. */
         for (int i = 0; i <= usuarios - 1; i++)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Favor elija el sexo del usuario");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Hombre");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Mujer");
            sexo[i] = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());             
            Console.WriteLine("Favor ingrese nombre {0}", (i + 1));
            nombres[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Favor ingrese la edad");
            edad[i] = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
         }

         Console.WriteLine("Las personas que pueden jubilarse son: ");

         /* En esta etapa, se mostraran en pantalla, las personas que por edad, alcanzaron a jubilarse. */
         for (int j = 0; j < nombres.Length; j++)
         {                
            if (edad[j] >= hombre || edad[j] >= mujer )
            {
               hombre = edad[j];
               mujer = edad[j];
               Console.WriteLine("{0}  con  {1} años", nombres[j], edad[j]);
            }          
         }         

         Console.WriteLine("Las personas que NO pueden jubilarse son: ");

         for (int j = 0; j < nombres.Length; j++)
         {
            if (edad[j] <= hombre || edad[j] <= mujer)
            {
                hombre = edad[j];
                mujer = edad[j];
                Console.WriteLine(" {0}  con  {1}  años", nombres[j], edad[j]);
            }
         }

         Console.ReadLine();

         return 0;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola Jeison, si la respuesta te resolvió tu problema podrías marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Las personas que pueden jubilarse son: ");

for (int j = 0; j < nombres.Length; j++)
{                
   if ((edad[j] >= hombre && sexo[j] == 0) || (edad[j] >= mujer && sexo[j] == 1))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} con {1} años", nombres[j], edad[j]);
   }          
}         

Console.WriteLine("Las personas que NO pueden jubilarse son: ");

for (int j = 0; j < nombres.Length; j++)
{
   if ((edad[j] < hombre && sexo[j] == 0) || (edad[j] < mujer && sexo[j] == 1))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(" {0} con {1} años", nombres[j], edad[j]);
   }
}
```

Debes cambiar tus condiciones, por ejemplo la condición para determinar quien se jubila debe ser:

```
if ((edad[j] >= hombre && sexo[j] == 0) || (edad[j] >= mujer && sexo[j] == 1))
```

Aquí estás preguntando por los hombres que pueden jubilarse y las mujeres que también pueden jubilarse, en la condición que tienes te faltó aclarar el sexo de las personas.

De igual forma para saber los que no pueden jubilarse la condición debe ser:

```
if ((edad[j] < hombre && sexo[j] == 0) || (edad[j] < mujer && sexo[j] == 1))
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Quedo agradecido.

Comment: @JeisonKastro si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada para que la publicación quede completa. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) y completa el [tour] para más información (y así ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio).